# Get reference on class from in-class struct method

Tags: c++, reference

I have this code:

```
//.h
class A
{
    struct B
    {
      void SomeMethod();
    }
    B b;
}
//.cpp
void A::B::SomeMethod()
{
    //here will be code
}
```

Can i get the link to the object of class `A` from `SomeMethod()`? Because `this` return reference on struct object `b`.

Maybe answer can be pretty easy to find, but I can't make a correct request.

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you pass pointer to A in constructor of B, and in constructor of A pass this to B ?

Comment: There is no connection from an object to any object that contains it. Or to put it another way, you can't find out what, if anything, is the owner of an object.

Comment: @Andrew You mean create pointer variable in `B` and store the pointer in it, right? I thought about that, but it sounds not good, maybe there are ways to get it directly

Comment: @molbdnilo, it's sad(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the design (B being private member of A) looks like the user shall only have the access to A class interfaces. Then what about just passing a parent class pointer to the method:

```
class A
{
    struct B
    {
      void SomeMethod(A* parent);
    };
    B b;
public:
    void callSomeMethod() { b.SomeMethod(this); }
};

//.cpp
void A::B::SomeMethod(A* parent)
{
    std::cout << "parent addr: " << parent << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << "a addr: " << &a << std::endl;
    a.callSomeMethod();
}
```